# Inserting String values in a 2D array of an Object type

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, type-conversion

I am trying to read contents from a file and put it into a 2D array of Object type Box. Its giving me a type error. Can somebody please help me?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Gameboard
{
  private Box[][] bx;

  public Gameboard (String fileNm)
   {
    try {

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(fileNm);
        Scanner lineReader = new Scanner(input.readLine());

        while (lineReader.next() != null)
        {
            bx = new Box[row][col];
            for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
               for(int j = 0; j < col; j++)
               {
                    bx[row][col] = lineReader.next(); // the error is here
               }
        }

}
```

Comment: And why do you expect this to work? You're trying to assign a ``String`` to a ``Box`` variable.

Comment: `next()` returns a string. You need to somehow create a `Box` object from it. If you share its code, we may be able to help with that.

Answer (score 1):

Yeap the error is expected. In `bx[row][col] = lineReader.next();` you attempt to read a value. `Scanner#next()` by default returns a `String` but you're attempting to store it an array of type `Box`.

Instead of doing that you should create a Box object an store it that way. Also, you know that you're not traversing all the rows and cols. `bx[row][col]` would mean that you'll be assigning a value to 5,7 (in this example).